# Cannot bypass boolean value in test class

Tags: trigger, unit-test, code-coverage

Trigger handler class:

```
public static void IsAfterUpdate(List<Account> lOld, Map<Id,Account> mOld, List<Account> lNew, Map<Id,Account> mNew){
    if (bypassAllTriggers || stopRecurrsionForUrlUpdate || stopFormulaRecurrsion || stopRecurrsion) {
        return;    
    }
    someMethod(mNew);
```

The stopRecurrsion is a global static variable which is set to true in `is before update` method. I need to run `someMethod(mNew)` for my code coverage issue. But cannot figure out a way to make it false, as it is changes on fly.

Is there a way to mock the `stopRecurrsion` to false wherever it is called?

Comment: which recursion? a method or a trigger which triggers itself after some DML operation?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
private static Boolean stopRecurrsion = false;
```

you can add a getter and a flag you can set from your test:

```
@TestVisible private static Boolean disableStopRecurrsion = false;

private static Boolean stopRecurrsion {
    get {
        if (disableStopRecurrsion) return false;
        if (stopRecurrsion == null) stopRecurrsion = false;
        return stopRecurrsion;
    }
    set;
}
```

Rather than focussing on test coverage, do think about the logic you are trying to assert and be sure that this change isn't undermining the logic you are trying to assert about.